# Missing widths in Times-Roman font in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, fonts

I have a [pdf](http://www.filedropper.com/r_3) which contains some character like dashes and double quotes on page number 8 having width 0.
It has Times-Roman font.

I have tried to find the width using AFM files for Times-Roman font but had no luck.

How can I find width of such characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Times Roman is one of the **Standard 14 Fonts**. These fonts oftentimes are exceptions in the PDF specification concerning required data, e.g.

> **Widths** array *(Required except for the standard 14 fonts;...*
>
> *(Table 111 – Entries in a Type 1 font dictionary - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

The section on these fonts explains where to get the information instead:

> The PostScript names of 14 Type 1 fonts, known as the *standard 14 fonts*, are as follows: Times-Roman, Helvetica, Courier, Symbol, Times-Bold, Helvetica-Bold, Courier-Bold, ZapfDingbats, Times-Italic, HelveticaOblique, Courier-Oblique, Times-BoldItalic, Helvetica-BoldOblique, Courier-BoldOblique
>
> These fonts, or their font metrics and suitable substitution fonts, shall be available to the conforming reader.
>
> NOTE The character sets and encodings for these fonts are listed in Annex D. The font metrics files for the standard 14 fonts are available from the ASN Web site (see the Bibliography). For more information on font metrics, see Adobe Technical Note #5004, *Adobe Font Metrics File Format Specification*.
>
> *(section 9.6.2.2 - Standard Type 1 Fonts (Standard 14 Fonts) - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Having clicked throught the Adobe sites it looks like font metrics currently are available at ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/type/

---

The OP clarified his problems in a comment:

> I have tried Adobe's Font metric file to get width value char \x93,\x94,\x96,\x97,\x98. However these values are not present in AFM file. How can I find widths of these values?

First of all you have to look up the meaning of those values.

You mentioned that the problem occurs on *page number 8* and the font being *Times-Roman*. On page 8 there are *Times-Roman* fonts **F28** and and **F46**, and there is a *Fimes-Bold* font **F43**. The other fonts are *Courier* and *CMSY10* (TeX Computer Modern Symbol?). **F28**, **F43**, and **F46** have the same **Encoding** entry:

```
163 0 obj
<</Differences
    [0/.notdef 1/dotaccent/fi/fl/fraction/hungarumlaut/Lslash/lslash/ogonek/ring 10/.notdef 11/breve/minus 13/.notdef 14/Zcaron/zcaron/caron/dotlessi/dotlessj/ff/ffi/ffl 22/.notdef 30/grave/quotesingle/space/exclam/quotedbl/numbersign/dollar/percent/ampersand/quoteright/parenleft/parenright/asterisk/plus/comma/hyphen/period/slash/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight/nine/colon/semicolon/less/equal/greater/question/at/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W/X/Y/Z/bracketleft/backslash/bracketright/asciicircum/underscore/quoteleft/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z/braceleft/bar/braceright/asciitilde 127/.notdef 130/quotesinglbase/florin/quotedblbase/ellipsis/dagger/daggerdbl/circumflex/perthousand/Scaron/guilsinglleft/OE 141/.notdef 147/quotedblleft/quotedblright/bullet/endash/emdash/tilde/trademark/scaron/guilsinglright/oe 157/.notdef 159/Ydieresis 160/.notdef 161/exclamdown/cent/sterling/currency/yen/brokenbar/section/dieresis/copyright/ordfeminine/guillemotleft/logicalnot/hyphen/registered/macron/degree/plusminus/twosuperior/threesuperior/acute/mu/paragraph/periodcentered/cedilla/onesuperior/ordmasculine/guillemotright/onequarter/onehalf/threequarters/questiondown/Agrave/Aacute/Acircumflex/Atilde/Adieresis/Aring/AE/Ccedilla/Egrave/Eacute/Ecircumflex/Edieresis/Igrave/Iacute/Icircumflex/Idieresis/Eth/Ntilde/Ograve/Oacute/Ocircumflex/Otilde/Odieresis/multiply/Oslash/Ugrave/Uacute/Ucircumflex/Udieresis/Yacute/Thorn/germandbls/agrave/aacute/acircumflex/atilde/adieresis/aring/ae/ccedilla/egrave/eacute/ecircumflex/edieresis/igrave/iacute/icircumflex/idieresis/eth/ntilde/ograve/oacute/ocircumflex/otilde/odieresis/divide/oslash/ugrave/uacute/ucircumflex/udieresis/yacute/thorn/ydieresis]
  /Type/Encoding>>
endobj
```

You are looking for *\x93,\x94,\x96,\x97,\x98*, i.e. (decimal) 147, 148, 150, 151, 152. According to the **Encoding** above, especially this **Differences** section:

```
147/quotedblleft/quotedblright/bullet/endash/emdash/tilde
```

that means **quotedblleft**, **quotedblright**, **endash**, **emdash**, and **tilde**. Searching for those names in the font metrics file one gets:

```
C 170 ; WX 444 ; N quotedblleft ; B 43 433 414 676 ;
C 186 ; WX 444 ; N quotedblright ; B 30 433 401 676 ;
C 177 ; WX 500 ; N endash ; B 0 201 500 250 ;
C 208 ; WX 1000 ; N emdash ; B 0 201 1000 250 ;
C 196 ; WX 333 ; N tilde ; B 1 532 331 638 ;
```

So here are the metrics, especially the widths, of your characters.

Comment: I have tried Adobe's Font metric file to get width value char \x93,\x94,\x96,\x97,\x98. However these values are not present in AFM file. How can I find widths of these values?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the way to find the widths of those characters.

Comment: I didn’t find the relevant AFM files in the FTP link given in this answer. But multiple Google searches I finally found them on https://www.adobe.com/devnet/font.html , near the bottom, "Font Metrics for PDF Core 14 Fonts".